# Press button with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[Path here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scDPt.png)

I need to press the button but cant really figure out how

I tried copying the xpath but get an error

also tried to press the button over the id or class_name but also not worked

If you have an idea please write it in the comments. Thanks

Tried so far:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='action-button']").click()
```

```py
driver.find_element_by_class_name("action-button").click()
```

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("[@id='clearBrowsingDataConfirm']").click()
```

```py
driver.find_element_by_id('[@id="clearBrowsingDataConfirm"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work if it's not in a iframe.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('clearBrowsingDataConfirm').click()
```

Try this if it's after driver.get()

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'clearBrowsingDataConfirm'))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Mhh. Not working think I also tried already one time. Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="clearBrowsingDataConfirm"]"}

Comment: Maybe try the following.

Comment: Exception has occurred: TimeoutException
Message:..............Looks like it doesnt find anything from what I have researched is that the button is in * / deep / and it cant be detected by selenium. So I simpy tried to send to the "body" element send.key(Keys.ENTER) but still dont work somehow.

Comment: What website is it on?

Comment: Well its a website in chrome options chrome://settings/clearBrowserData I want to delete tge browser cache.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('* /deep/ #clearBrowsingDataConfirm').click() should work for you.